# Dowloading a file from the packer instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami, packer

- I am using Packer to create AMI's.
- So Packer creates a temporary security group and keypair etc and launches an Insatnce.In my usecase after installing all the packages I need to run some test.Hence the results are generated on the same Instance which was launched by packer.

I want those results.Basically I want to download the results file on the machine which triggered the packer build.Is there a way in packer itself to download any or any other way.

Thanks in Advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I Actually did not get any help on this.

The solution I found on this in a hacky way was:

- I created a bash script which basically uploads the result.xml(Test result) to S3.
- And do not forget to give correct permission to the s3 bucket, so that the packer instance    can access it.
- And download the result file after the packer run is completed from S3.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs into this today, you can use the `direction` option to switch to download:

https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/file#direction